# Swift custom button class

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to create a custom class that creates a button. I'm having trouble adding a target to that button inside it's class. This is my code

```
class SelectButton{

        var button:UIButton = UIButton()

        init(button_frame: CGRect, button_title: String, connected: [UIButton]?){
            self.button.frame = button_frame
            self.button.setTitle(button_title, for: UIControlState.normal)
            self.button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        }

        func construct() -> UIButton {
            return self.button
        }

        @objc func buttonPressed() {
            print("Button Clicked")
        }
}
```

The problem is that I can't connect an action on button click. This works if it's used outside my class but not inside.

Usage of the class

```
let test = SelectButton(button_frame: CGRect(x:50, y:50, width: 250, height:150), button_title: "Test button", connected: nil).construct()
self.view.addSubview(test)
```

Comment: How are you using this class?  Show that code. Why did you not subclass `UIButton`?

Comment: I edited my question, because I think this is better than subclassing `UIButton`

Comment: Nothing is holding a strong reference to your `SelectButton` instance, so as soon as the function that creates `test` exits, that instance is released.  The button itself is retained because you have added it as a subview, so it is still visible but there is no longer an object to respond to the action. Really `SelectButton` should subclass `UIButton` then you could add the `SelectButton` as the subview.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Subclassing `UIButton` solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When someone taps the button, usually you want something to happen somewhere else in your app (like in one of your view controllers or in some other UI element). The way the IBAction is set up right now, you have it so that something will trigger or happen within the button itself when someone taps on it. If you want to handle a button tap programmatically instead of ctrl dragging from the button into the view controller, you can do it this way if you prefer. First, add this code into the view controller:

```
 @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

}
```

Then you can either add the selector programmatically by adding this method into your view controller:

```
 myButton.addTarget(self, action:self.buttonPressed(sender), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Or by going to the connections inspector and dragging from the touch up inside over to the IBAction dot in your view controller code. Also, as someone else pointed out in the comments you should make your button inherit from UIButton by adding this to your class declaration:

```
 class SelectButton: UIButton {
   . . .
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is holding a strong reference to your `SelectButton` instance, so as soon as the function that creates `test` exits, that instance is released.

The button itself is retained because you have added it as a subview. Therefore, it is still visible but there is no longer an object to respond to the action.

You either need to use an instance property rather than a local variable for `test`, or, preferably have `SelectButton` inherit directly from `UIButton`